# How can I detect a WM_PAINT event in a different process?

Tags: c#, winapi

I'd like to detect when a Windows control is rendered in another process. It's easy to detect changes in a window's location with SetWinEventHook:

```
SetWinEventHook(EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE, EVENT_OBJECT_LOCATIONCHANGE, IntPtr.Zero, moveListener, 0, 0, WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT);
```

but I can't get this to work with WM_PAINT of a component in that window. I can capture the events with Spy++.

The purpose of this is to measure the performance of a third party application. I can capture the time that a message is sent to the application to load images (they are loaded over the network). I was imagining being able to set a hook listening for an event when the command was submitted to load the images, capture the time that the event occurred, then unhooking the listener.

If there is a different way to approach this I'm all ears. Thanks.

Comment: You would need to inject code into the target process and sub-class the target window.

Comment: I was afraid of that :-). If you change your comment to an answer I can accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @SeanDoyle were you able to achieve it? Could you please direct me to a sample code?

Comment: @Ram - sorry - I did not continue on this path. The application that I would have to inject the DLL into was a clinical application and the support staff would not have supported a strategy using this mechanism.